# How to force Android Emulator to work on full speed, even when it is out of focus?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to use Jake Wharton's https://github.com/JakeWharton/adb-event-mirror to catch a bug but the second Android emulator instance is extremely slow. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Physical Android devices will run much faster but assuming you have a good amount of RAM on your machine you can give a higher value for "RAM" in "Memory and Storage" from your AVD Manager for the associated emulator you are running in Android Studio. That should speed things up.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, doesn't work. I want to run two simulator instances at the same speed simultaneously.

Comment: Ah okay I see now. Do you have two physical devices? If so, you could use wireless ADB if you're limited from a hardware standpoint to have two USB connections for wireless devices.

Comment: The script I'm trying to use only supports devices up to sdk-25. I only have devices with sdk-29, so it's not applicable for my hardware devices :(

Comment: Got it, and you've tried matching the RAM designations for both of your emulators?